# NSCoding - Protocol Methods (encodeWithCoder, initWithCoder) Repeated Code

Tags: ios, nscoding, boilerplate

I am using NSCoding for local data persistence. I have a bunch of model classes that need to be stored locally. I've been implementing encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder protocol methods for hours. But it's not actually "coding", it's just repeating the following three steps:

1. Find the variables that need to be stored locally.
2. Write encodeWithCoder given those variables.
3. Write initWithCoder given those variables.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8938097/1271826

Answer (score 0):

Just make all of your classes inherit from a single class that does all the NSCoding stuff.